# Discriminating tuple not working as expected

Tags: typescript, overloading

I just learned the method of using discriminating tuple as parameter from the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56849033/cannot-get-method-overloading-together-with-discriminatory-union-to-work-what-i), but as I tried the concept on some of my old codes, I found that I couldn't get it to work as I expected. Consider the following example:

```
class Fraction {
    constructor(r: Rational) {
        /* Not important */
    }
}
type Rational = number | Fraction;

class Couple {
    private _x: Fraction;
    private _y: Fraction;

    constructor(c: Couple);
    constructor(x: Rational, y: Rational);
    constructor(...r: [Couple] | [Rational, Rational]) {
        if(r[0] instanceof Couple) r = [r[0]._x, r[0]._y]; // pay attention here
        this._x = new Fraction(r[0]);
        this._y = new Fraction(r[1]);
    }
}
```

I'm expecting that, after the line indicated above, TypeScript should conclude that `r` can only be of the type `[Rational, Rational]` and should have no problem with the next two lines, but that's not the case. Why is that and how can I fix this while still using the tuple idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this tuple is not really a discriminated union. A discriminated union must have a discriminant property, a property is a discriminant property if:

1. The property is a literal type as outlined here [9163](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/9163)
2. The a property of a union type to be a discriminant property if it has a union type containing at least one unit type and no instantiable types as outlined here [27695](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27695)

See [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30506#issuecomment-474802840) comment

We can transform this into a discriminated union, if we add an extra element to the first tuple, so we satisfy the second case outlined above:

```
class Fraction {
    constructor(r: Rational) {
        /* Not important */
    }
}
type Rational = number | Fraction;

class Couple {
    private _x: Fraction;
    private _y: Fraction;

    constructor(c: Couple);
    constructor(x: Rational, y: Rational);
    constructor(...r: [Couple, undefined?] | [Rational, Rational]) {
        if(r[1] === undefined) r = [r[0]._x, r[0]._y]; 
        this._x = new Fraction(r[0]); // ok
        this._y = new Fraction(r[1]); // ok
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, but why is the second condition formulated that way? Could you explain the reason for requiring no instantiable types?

Comment: @Mu-TsunTsai The PRs I link to are all the insight I have into the decision process for these. I am not sure if there is a soundness issue or an implementation issue with allowing classes and `instanceof` to discriminate unions or a not enough demand to implement issue. All i can tell you is that what  a discriminant property must look like for it to work 